# Implicit authentication for DocuSign Embedded Signing

Tags: php, oauth, docusignapi

I have tried the code grant examples(PHP) given in the API and they are working perfectly fine but for those examples i was trying implicit authentication but its not working. I'm not familiar with twig function used how to play with it.

I'm also new to Docusign, Can anyone help me with the php code that can be used for implicit authentication for generating access token and also handle if token expires.

OR

IS there a way by which users can sign on embedded document on my website through docusign implicit authentication without logging in to Docusign

I have tried code examples given in documentation of Docusign

I need users to sign on document who are already registered on my site after they log in.(Note: They dont have to login to Docusign)

Any help much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: I managed to generate access token, Can anyone help in using https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo along with access token to get base_uri ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Re: how can a signer sign a document on my website? The signer has an account on my website and logs into my website.

After the signer logs into your website, you know who they are (name and, optionally, email).

In this case, your signers do **not** need a login with DocuSign.

Instead, your application should use the JWT Grant to access DocuSign on behalf of the person who sent (or will send) the envelope.

This user is sometimes called a "system user" or "application user" since it is a DocuSign user account that is used by your application itself. (It's the same as any other DocuSign user account.)

After creating the envelope your application obtains the URL for the signing ceremony for the specific signer using [EnvelopeViews::createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient)

Your application then redirects to the signing ceremony and the signer can sign.

**Signers do NOT need a login to the DocuSign system**

> Re: Using the OAuth Implicit Grant flow

The Implicit Grant flow is used when a person wants to authenticate 
with DocuSign itself and the application does not have a backend server 
component. For example, the application runs entirely in the browser using the React framework.

In your use case, Implicit Grant should not be used since your signers
do not need a login on DocuSign. Instead, your application should use
the JWT Grant to impersonate a "system user" that will be used with DocuSign.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification. It helped me a lot in taking right steps. Once again thanks a lot

Comment: @SiddheshShirodkar -- glad to help! Thank you for using DocuSign and thank you for the check!